# Disable Fontification in Org-Mode while Keeping Color Highlighting

Tags: org-mode, faces, font-lock, highlighting, customize-face

I would like to ask a question about org-mode and font-lock-mode.

I just started using Emacs and, since I am not a programmer, I use it
mostly for writing and handling texts. And, I am quite interested in
org-mode because I heard it is the best tool for pretty much anything
I can do with texts. Of course, I tried it.

However, I found one thing which bothers me. It is not an actual
"problem" but a matter of my "preference". I do not like the
fontification of org-mode. (ex: italic or bold) I do not want it to
hide any markup elements. (ex: brackets for hyperlinks) I just want
plain text showing everything without any visual effects. I want to
see such visual effects only when it is exported to other format like
HTML. I want to see only plain text in the text editor.

I googled and found out font-lock-mode. It was very close to what I
wanted. But, there is one problem. When it is turned off, color
highlighting disappears too. Even though I want plain text, still I
want it to be colorful.

I tried my best but could not find a solution. But, considering the
flexibility of Emacs, I am quite sure that there is a way. I just
cannot find it. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Font-lock isn't your problem, if you want to keep having it color text.

If you just want to change the appearance font-lock gives you for some particular faces, e.g., by removing their boldness or whatever, then just *customize the faces that you don't like*. Boldness, like color, is just a face property/attribute.

Put your cursor on such text, and hit `C-u C-x =`, to see which face(s) are present there. Then use `M-x customize-face` to customize the problematic face.

You can also use `M-x list-faces-display`, to see all faces, compare them, etc. And in that display you can just click a face name to do what `M-x customize-face` does.

Comment: The various faces that Org mode uses for fontification are defined in the file `org-faces.el`. They all belong to the customization group `org-faces` so you can say `M-x customize-group org-faces` and go through them, find out which one does what and customize them as you wish.

Comment: Thank you, Drew and NickD. Now I understand that it can be done with "M-x customize-face" or "M-x customize-group". But, unfortunately, it looks kind of overwhelming because there are too many options and I do not know which item does what. I think there is no one-line code which can conveniently achieve what I wanted. Definitely, I will need a lot more time to experiment and find optimal settings for me.

Comment: Right: but you can change one thing at a time and make sure it does what you want before going on to the next thing. You will be able to get through it all in fairly short order. So don't rush it: you can live with face imperfections for a little while, particularly if you see them going away one by one.

Comment: I found a temporary measure, which is not perfect but very close to what I wanted. Though this may be something obvious to experienced users, still I am sharing this for beginners like me. Adding `(setq org-fontify-emphasized-text nil)` & `(setq org-descriptive-links nil)` to my `init.el`, I could disable emphasis fontifications and prevent hiding brackets for links.

Comment: OP: Put that in an answer, not in a comment, if you want it to help others. Comments can be deleted at any time. (You can accept your own answer, BTW.)

Answer (score 2):

I found a temporary measure, which is not perfect but very close to what I wanted. Though this may be something obvious to experienced users, still I am sharing this for beginners like me:

`(setq org-fontify-emphasized-text nil)`
`(setq org-descriptive-links nil)`

Adding these 2 lines to my `init.el`, I could disable emphasis fontifications and prevent hiding brackets for links.